# If Mellin transform of a function has a pole at $s=\sigma+it$, then the function is not $o(x^{\sigma})$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

Let Mellin transform of a function $f(x):[1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by:

$$F(s)=\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)x^{-s-1}dx$$

I am trying to prove the following:

> If $F(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=\sigma+it$, then $f(x)\neq o(x^{\sigma})$.

My line of thought is, assume $f(x)=o(x^{\sigma})$. Since $F(s)$ has pole at $\sigma+it$, $F(\sigma+it)$ is asymptotic to $\frac{C}{(s-\sigma-it)}$ for some constant $C$. On the other hand let $|f(x)|<\frac{|C|}{2}x^{\sigma}$ for some $x>A$, the integral becomes:

$$\int_{1}^{A}f(x)x^{-s-1}dx+\int_{A}^{\infty}f(x)x^{-s-1}dx<O(1)+\frac{|C|}{2|(s-\sigma)|}$$

Compare the singular part, the coefficient does not match, contradiction.

**Edit**

The singular part of $|F(s)|$ is $\frac{|C|}{|s-\sigma-it|}$, while the singular part is also less than $\frac{|C|}{2|s-\sigma-it|}$, which is a contradiction.

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: You need absolute values when estimating the integrals. "Compare the singular part, the coefficient does not match, contradiction." would need a bit more elaboration.

Comment: It should be $O(1)+\frac{|C|}{2\Re(s-\sigma)}$ not $O(1)+\frac{|C|}{2|s-\sigma|}$